# Two objects moving relativistically towards each other

Tags: special-relativity

Let's say I have two objects moving relativistically toward each other, so the object on the left is moving to the right, say, at .3c and the object on the right is moving to the left at .7c, and they are some distance apart. How would I set up a problem like this to find at what position they meet and at what respective times (do I need to consider each frame?). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\def\ns#1#2{#1_{\rm#2}} \def\vA{\ns vA} \def\vB{\ns vB} \def\tA{\ns
tA} \def\xA{\ns xA} \def\xB{\ns xB} \def\tauA{\ns\tau A} \def\cA{{\cal A}} \def\cB{{\cal B}} \let\D=\Delta \def\KA{\ns{\rm K}A} \def\KB{\ns{\rm K}B}$
I want to show how to solve your problem with no use of coordinates and Lorentz transformations - only Minkowski geometry and and spacetime
invariant.

You are given two objects, let us call them A and B (to the right of A). You didn't say, but are initially working in a frame K, and give us both velocities in this frame: $\vA=0.3\,c$ and $\vB=-0.7\,c$. As already remarked by Rodney, you must also know the initial distance (say at $t=0$, $t$ being
time of K frame). Call it $d$.

It is also worth considering two events: $E$ is along A's worldline,
$F$ along B's worldline. According to measurements in frame K, $E$ and
$F$ are simultaneous ($t=0$). A third event $G$ is the encounter
between A and B. Event $G$ is at the intersection of A's and B's
worldlines.

[image]

All this is represented in the figure, where you can see two straight
lines, marked $\cA$ and $\cB$, representing the worldlines. Events $E$
and $F$ are connected by a horizontal line, to show their simultaneity
in K. Event $G$, as already said, is at intersection between $\cA$ and
$\cB$.

Let $\D t$ be the time interval between $E$ and $G$ as measured in K (it
is also the time interval between $F$ and $G$). I wish to note at this
point that in frame K, as in every inertial frame you happen to
consider, you must not think of *one* clock, but of an array of
clocks, ideally infinite, all synchronized one with another. When we
talk about time intervals measured in K between events happening in
different places, you must always keep in mind that *two* clocks are
involved, one for each event.

In time $\D t$ object A has moved, wrt K, by $\vA\D t$, object B by
$\vB\D t$. Their distance, which was $d$ initially, has become
$d+(\vB-\vA)\,\D t$.  But at their encounter (event $G$) distance is 0, then
$$\D t = {d \over \vA - \vB}.$$

As to A's and B's displacements, they are
$$\D\xA = \vA\D t \qquad \D\xB = \vB\D t$$
(don't forget that $\vB$ is negative).

---

You ask "the respective times" at which A and B meet. In principle, this means to switch to one of two novel frames: $\KA$ or $\KB$. The former is the frame in which A is resting, the latter the same for B. We can use the invariance of interval:
$$c^2 \D t^2 - \D x^2 = c^2 \D t'^2 - \D x'^2 \tag 1$$ 
where, for two frames K, K$'$ and for any couple of events, $\D t$, $\D x$
are their time and space separations as measured in K, $\D t'$ and $\D x'$ the same for K$'$.

Applying (1) to frames $\rm K$, $\KA$ and to events E, G we have
$$c^2 \D t^2 - \D\xA^2 = c^2 \D\tauA^2.\tag 2$$
This is because time and space separations in K are $\D t$, $\D\xA$,
whereas in $\KA$ the requested time separation I called $\D\tauA$ and
the space separation is null. From eq. (2) $\D\tauA$ can be computed,
since we already found $\D t$ and $\D\xA$. Same calculation applies
for B.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with three reference frames in the set-up. First, there is the 'lab' frame in which the given velocities are measured. Second, there is the rest frame of object 1. In this frame, the speed of object 2 will be greater than 0.7$c$ but less than $c$. Finally, there is the rest frame of object 2. In this frame, the speed of object 1 will be greater than 0.3$c$, but again less than $c$. We can assume that all three frames are in the standard orientation, so that all the axes are parallel. We can also assume there is a clock attached to each object, and a third clock at rest in the lab frame, and that all three clocks are synchronized at the instant the two objects are separated by a distance $d$ as measured in the lab frame.

Finding the $(t, x)$ coordinates of the collision in the 'lab' frame will not require anything beyond ordinary kinematics, but you will need to specify the starting distance between the objects. Call that distance $d$. Then the position of object 1 at $t = 0$ can be set to $x = 0$, and the position of object 2 at $t = 0$ can be set to $x = d$. Object 1's position changes according to

$$x_1 = (0.3c)t,$$

and object 2's position changes according to

$$x_2 = d - (0.7c)t.$$

For a given $d$, you can determine the time and position of the collision as measured in the lab frame.

In the rest frames of the objects, you will need to find the speed and position of the moving (other) object using the Lorentz transformation (transforming from the lab frame to each object's rest frame). In each frame, the collision occurs at the origin ($x = 0$) of that frame. But the elapsed times--the proper times measured by the clocks attached to the objects--will be different because the clocks attached to objects 1 and 2 are not ticking at the same rate compared to each other or to the lab clock.

Comment: "But the elapsed times [...] will be different because the clocks
attached to objects 1 and 2 are not ticking at the same rate
compared to each other [...]" If you say so, you should expect a question: "Which of the clocks 1 and 2 ticks faster?" Surely you know that this is a most delicate point. It is necessary to insist that when 1 takes readings of clock 2, it does so by comparing that single clock with *two* clocks in 1's frame, placed in the *two different positions* object 2 occupies, in 1's frame, at the beginning and at the end of some time interval. And *vice versa*.

Comment: Elio: He asked for the setup, so I intentionally limited my answer except for explaining why he needed to specify $d$ to get started. I up-voted your answer.